Concentration of spectator ions halves?
I have a question below that I'm not too sure about.

A precipitation reaction is caused by mixing 100mL of 0.25M $\ce{Na2Cr2O7}$ with 100 mL of 0.25M $\ce{Pb(NO3)2}$. The precipitate is filtered from the mixture. How would the concentration of the spectator ions be affected as the reaction occurs?

I put my answer as not affected, but the answer key as both spectator ions will halve in concentration. Why? I thought concentration ions can't change in concentration. (I couldn't find anything when I searched online about the changing of spectator ions unfortunately)

The amount did not change, but the volume doubled.

The concentration would be changed because the volume doubled when you combined the two solutions.

If you say they first mixed and then reacted, you’d be right in saying that the reaction does not affect the concentration. The mixing does, though.

Sometimes, there is the right answer that is not expected and the expected answer that is not right. If applicable, provide both with comments, or challenge the teacher.  // I assume the concentration changes due dilution alone have not confused you, as $\dfrac{n_1 }{ V_1} \ne \dfrac{n_1 }{ V_1 + V_2}$

The purpose of the question is to make it obvious that when 2 substances, solutions, condensed phases are mixed, dissolved, their concentrations change [Though not necessarily their activities if they are pure substances that do not interact or dissolve]. Not so for gases, here both the pressure and volume are considered. Changes in concentration can have an effect on solubility, reaction rates, and equilibria.
The question has no answer since it depends on the mechanics of the process. Are the solutions mixed quickly or slowly, both together, A into B, or B into A. Is the precipitation reaction quick or slow; do the substances dissolve as ions or molecules.
I am answering this because I just reread my quant book on sulfate analysis where it explained the problems of coprecipitation depending on order of mix and rate of mix of the reactants. Also Chromium plating baths require a small concentration of sulfate ions to plate properly. The analysis for sulfate is difficult because of the chromate [not a spectator, a bystander and participant]. Order of mixing, rate of mixing, can have a profound effect on a reaction, on kinetics, heat formation, even on the actual reaction and is not trivial.
